# How to find all possible way to combination sum

Tags: python, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

Given a list of numbers and a value,return the number of ways to generate the value
using the numbers in the list. You can use a number multiple times.
Don't use any built-in functions or library

```
Example:
list = [1,2,3]
target = 4

expected result: [[1,1,1,1], [1,1,2], [1,2,1], [2,1,1], [2,2], [1,3], [3+1]], 7 ways
```

I have backtrack code like this:

```
def combinationSum(candidates, target):
    result = []
    def backtrack(pos, target, currentCombination):
        if target == 0:
            print("new combination", currentCombination)
            result.append(currentCombination[::])
            return    
        if pos == len(candidates) or target < 0:
            return    
        for i in range(pos, len(candidates)):
            currentElement = candidates[i]
            currentCombination.append(currentElement)
            backtrack(i, target-currentElement, currentCombination)
            currentCombination.pop()        
    backtrack(0, target, [])   
    return result
```

Output is : `[[1,1,1,1], [1,1,2], [1,3], [2,2]` it print only 4 ways

Please help me fix that code and print the result same expect result
I try to find all questions but it not what i want